# jq - apply modifications from a file

Tags: json, jq, updates

I have some json content in a file: *content.json*

```
{
  "Type": {
    "OS": "Windows"
  },
  "Network": {
     "Protocol": "unknown",
     "Port": 80
  }
}
```

And some json updates in a file: *updates.json*

```
{
  "Network": {
    "Protocol": "HTTP"
  }
}
```

How can I use jq to read *updates.json* and apply its content to *content.json*?
CAVEAT: I cannot predict the what's in *updates.json*. The jq script must be smart enough to just apply whatever it finds.
The output should be:

```
{
  "Type": {
    "OS": "Windows"
  },
  "Network": {
     "Protocol": "HTTP",
     "Port": 80
  }
}
```

This script does *almost* what I want:

```
jq 'add' -s content.json updates.json
```

The results are:

```
{
  "Type": {
    "OS": "Windows"
  },
  "Network": {
    "Protocol": "HTTP"
  }
}
```

But as you can see, the "Port" entry is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the "recursive addition" operator `*` will meet your needs:

```
< contents.json  jq --argfile updates updates.json '
  . * $updates
'
```

Comment: That's it! I had a feeling it would turn out to be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Just did that. I first tried to upvote and it wouldn't let me so I stopped there.

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrates one approach you could take:

```
< content.json jq --argfile updates updates.json '
    .Network += $updates.Network
'
```

Or, depending on your precise requirements, you might like to consider:

```
< content.json jq --argfile updates updates.json '
  .Network |= with_entries(select(.value != "unknown"))
  | .Network += $updates.Network
'
```

Comment: It seems like that approach requires knowledge that the change is in the .Network section. Is there a more generic way that would apply to anything found in the updates file?

Comment: Yes, as illustrated in the separate answer.  There are numerous possibilities, depending on your precise requirements.

Comment: I suppose I'm looking for something that would turn the keys in the updates file into an iterable array rather than hardcoding the the names in the code.

Comment: That would be possible too, but maybe `*` will suffice as shown in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the occurrences of "unknown" to determine the updates:

```
< content.json jq --argfile updates updates.json '
  reduce paths(. == "unknown") as $p (.;
    setpath($p; $updates | getpath($p)) )
'
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic method:

```
jq -s 'def multiply:reduce .[] as $i ({}; . * $i);
       multiply' content.json updates.json
```

So you can put multiple files.